# light flickering on alpha texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency, lighting

for some reason, the lights are not working properly on alpha texture
[image]

see the end of hair on forehead and also the plate near the spoon and fork
it seems to emit this silver color
[image]

[image]

the shadow on the tree at the  flickers not working
[image]

it seems to happen when alpha texture is overlapping with one another
[image]
[image]

how do i fix this?
is it the material properties on texture?

Comment: if you are in Cycles, don't let faces overlap otherwise it will appear black, is it your problem here?

Comment: well no, it doesnt appear black, but the shadow casting from the object is flickering, open the first and second, or the third and fourth image on new tab, then compare them. when the alpha is infront or behind one another, the shadow seems to flicker, even when far apart